# Dynamic Replacement of a Command in a Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to reference an Excel command as a variable. Example:

```
=Average(A1:A5)
=Max(A1:A5)
```

Can I point to a cell with the contents "Average" vs 'Max" and use this in the formula such as with the following table placed in cells A1:D5.

```
1   Red     Max      Orange
2   Green   Min      Red
3   Blue    Average  Blue
4   Black       
5   Orange      

= MAX(A1.A5)
```

becoming (Cell Contents of C1, C2 or C3 to represent MAX, MIN, AVERAGE)

`=C1(A1.A5)`

Comment: Not without vba.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious INDIRECT() only returns valid range references, it will not evaluate a string as a formula.

Comment: I've never tried using Indirect like this, but I will now.... And let you know how it goes. **Recomment** - *No joy. Did not work. Must be a cell reference.*  **Re-recomment** @ScottCraner *I had never tried `Indirect` in such a way so I figured it was worth a shot.  Hit a wall right out of the gate and the documentation is very clear, you're spot on.*

Answer (score 0):

Here are two UDF's that do as requested.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Public Function nojoy(s As String, r As Range) As String
    Select Case s
        Case "Min"
            nojoy = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(r)
        Case "Max"
            nojoy = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(r)
        Case "Average"
            nojoy = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(r)
    End Select
End Function

Public Function nojoyLookup(s As String, r As Range, r1) As String
Dim s1 As String
    Select Case s
        Case "Min"
            s1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(r)
        Case "Max"
            s1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(r)
        Case "Average"
            s1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(r)
    End Select
    nojoyLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(r1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Val(s1), r, 0))
End Function
```